# Xamarin Forms 4.5: Converting pdf into byte array using Forms9Patch to create pdf and then print to bluetooth printer with byte array

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-bluetooth

I'm using Forms9Patch to convert html to pdf and then send the pdf file into a byte array to send into a bluetooth printer. I am able to save the file, but it is not printing the pdf file. Any clues to what I am doing wrong?:

```
 if (await Forms9Patch.ToPdfService.ToPdfAsync(htmlString, "PrintFileName") is ToFileResult result)
            {
                if (result.IsError)
                {
                    using (Forms9Patch.Toast.Create("PDF Error", result.Result)) { }
                }
                else
                {
                    var entry = new Forms9Patch.MimeItemCollection();
                    entry.AddBytesFromFile("application/pdf", result.Result);

                    string path = result.Result;
                    byte[] buffer = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);

                    string s = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);

                    DependencyService.Get<Services.IService>().Print(selectedPrinterBthDevice, result.Result, buffer);                    
                }
            }
```

In Android file (the important parts):

```
if (bluetoothSocket != null)
{
    await bluetoothSocket.ConnectAsync();

    if (bluetoothSocket.IsConnected)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Connected!");

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tText))
        {
            byte[] bufferTest = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(tText);
            bluetoothSocket.OutputStream.Write(bufferTest, 0, bufferTest.Length);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have any reason to think that simply sending a PDF as a byte array to the printer WILL work?  Printers rarely accept raw data streams like that.  Have you read the printer documentation?

Comment: Yeah, It'll be a good idea to read the printer documentations. Thanks.